# Nodejs Express Server Doesn't Respond to HTTP POST: OpenShift

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

For my first experience using Node, I have hosted a Nodejs server on Openshift that I am hoping to use for an Android application server soon. Currently, I'm trying to get a simple express app that will respond to an HTTP POST request. Here is the code for this server; I've made it as simple as possible, and it responds to GET requests just fine, but the POST callback never seems to execute:

```
#!/bin/env node
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    res.end("Post successful.");
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.end("App listening on port: " + process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, 
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP, function() {
        console.log("Server started on %s.", Date(Date.now()));
});
```

Here is the Node script that I have been using to test the response. I do not believe it is the issue, because I have also tried POSTing in Java and using an HTML form, but neither of those seem to work either:

```
var http = require('http');

var data = JSON.stringify({
    'message' : 'hello'
});

var options = {
    host: 'xx-xx.rhcloud.com',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};

var request = http.request(options, function(res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', function(err) {
        console.log("Post successful");
    });
});

request.write(data);
request.end();
```

I can get the callback to execute when running the server locally, but only if I hard-code the port and the IP at that point. Once I start the server, it responds to the GET request with the port, which I assumed would always be 8080, but even hard-coding 8080 for the port on the host doesn't resolve the issue. Still, I'm assuming it's an issue with the port because my posting script and browser both hang up when I try to send the request, instead of throwing a connection error. Granted, I'm a complete noob and I could easily be overlooking a simple but critical element. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works ok if you put localhost and some port, so I guess you are having trouble configure that?

Comment: It works fine using localhost for me too. The problem occurs when I try to POST to the server that is hosted on OpenShift.

Answer (score 1):

This probably speaks to my inexperience with web technology in general, but I discovered the problem; when trying to POST to a particular port, the server is unresponsive. If, however, I remove the port declaration altogether from my POSTing script, then it works correctly. Could somebody maybe explain why that is?

Comment: Your application is being served at port 80 (the default HTTP port) by OpenShift. By removing the port from the URL, you are in effect specifying port 80 in the URL, which is why it is now working. It looks like you confused the internal port that OpenShift requires your application to bind to (usually 8080) with the port it is actually being served on, which will always be port 80 on OpenShift.

Comment: That would make sense then why a browser would work in this case, but does that mean that all POST requests by default are sent to port 80?

Comment: Yes, HTTP defaults to port 80. If you don't specify a port (it doesn't matter if it is a GET or POST request) it will default to port 80. Likewise HTTPS defaults to port 443. If you specify `http://` without specifying a port, it is going to use port 80. If you specify `https://` without specifying a port, it is going to use port 443. On OpenShift, both HTTP and HTTPS traffic is routed to port 8080 on your server.

Comment: @mbaird, one more question if you're familiar with Node. I'm hosting this server using the free package provided by OpenShift, which allows for 3 web applications without requiring payment. To improve performance, I was thinking I would have multiple servers that are dedicated to one task, such as logging in, sending messages, and sending notifications. Do I need to create separate HTTP servers to facilitate this? If so, will each one count as a separate web app?

Comment: That isn't going to work on OpenShift. It's also probably overkill unless you anticipate tons of traffic. On OpenShift you can scale out your application by running the same code on multiple servers. To run different code on different servers you would need to create entirely new applications on OpenShift, but then they wouldn't share a database. It really sounds like you just need to create separate pages or endpoints in your application for each task. Then if you need better performance you could distribute the load across multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might arrive late, but having solved the same issue here, maybe this will help others.

Say your app has the following public URL:

```
http://xyz-dercetech.rhcloud.com/api/authenticate
```

It goes unresponsive.

-> rhcloud.com has its own internal routing, so the process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_* won't help outside of their own server. Your NodeJS app binds to an internal ip & port, but that ip is not public.

Using the above public URI, you'll enjoy GET request passing through seamlessly. But as you said, POSTing will fail.

Just add the https port in your URI:

```
http://xyz-dercetech.rhcloud.com:443/api/authenticate
```